# athena array_agg sort by multiple values results in incorrect order

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

AWS Athena's `array_agg`, when sorted by multiple values, can return an incorrect order.

Here is the min repro

```
with xxx(id, sort_by, val) as (
    values
       (1, 'a' , 999),
       (1, 'b', 555)
)
select
    id,
    array_agg(val order by sort_by) as single_sort,     -- [999, 555]
    array_agg(val order by sort_by, val) as dual_sort   -- [555, 999]
from
    xxx
group by
    id
```

Result

```
id | single_sort |  dual_sort |
-------------------------------
 1 |  [999, 555] | [555, 999] |
```

I checked Presto and PostgreSQL and they both return the correct `[999, 555]` for single and dual sorts.

Does anyone know if this issue is being tracked, or have a suggested work around that can support arbitrary data types?

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete work around:

Convert multi-column sorts to a composite type using `row()` to force athena to sort them together.

```sql
with xxx(id, sort_by, val) as (
    values
       (1, 'a' , 999),
       (1, 'b', 555)
)
select
    id,
    array_agg(val order by sort_by) as single_sort,     -- [999, 555]
    array_agg(val order by row(sort_by, val)) as dual_sort   -- [999, 555]
from
    xxx
group by
    id
```

note

```sql
array_agg(val order by row(sort_by, val))
```

vs

```sql
array_agg(val order by sort_by, val)
```

but that only works if all values are being sorted in the same direction (asc/desc)